# Unable to save InfoPath 2010 form

Tags: infopath

I have a InfoPath form with two buttons one to save and other to submit. On save user can save the form temporarily and can comeback again and edit the form and fill in and submit it when entirely form is filled. On save I am checking if title is blank condition to show the save button. There is a view with some 5 cost fields with validation rules (if the cost field is blank throw error). So now when the title field is filled and user trying to just save the form the form is throwing error of validation but it should throw error only when the user hits Submit without filling cost fields. How can I avoid this while saving?

[image: enter code here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to remove the validation rules for those fields. Took a variable and initiating it with 0 on form load and comparing the variable with rules on each of the field by "variablecount + 1" and showing custom user message regarding error. This way when I am trying to save it won't throw any error.